# Adding images to a list of objects in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a list of images in C#. My problem is that I'm not sure how to reference the image in order to add it to the list. I've tried adding the file path in the parentheses, but it throws the error "cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Image'." Below is an example of what I've tried.

I'm very new to this so apologies if there is an obvious mistake or solution. Thank you! :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imageList = new List<Image>();
    imageOne = new Image("image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I think you may be looking for Image.FromFile("image.jpg").
Refer to this link for more information: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `imageList = new List<Image> { Image.FromFile(pathToImageFile) };`

Comment: Off-topic, but you are re-creating your `imageList` everytime your button gets clicked and never add `imageOne` to the list. Instantiate your list outside from the button click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) is an abstract class. That means you can't `new` it

Try [FromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
imageOne = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
```

It returns an `Image` object and you can add it into the list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load an image from a file, there is the [FromFile method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ex from msdn:

```
private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\" +
            @"All Users\Documents\My Music\music.bmp", true);

        TextureBrush texture = new TextureBrush(image1);
        texture.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(texture, 
            new RectangleF(90.0F, 110.0F, 100, 100));
        formGraphics.Dispose();

    }
    catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
            "Please check the path.");
    }

}
```

You also have the [FromStream method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to load an image from a stream.